Python GTK3 loading font files
Are people not using CSS with GTK3 in Python? I thought that was the recommended route now, but I don't see much discussion about it, and I haven't gotten much feedback on my posts. The GTK3 docs (https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html) also don't seem to cover all cases. Are there other docs or tutorials that I'm missing?
And as far as I can tell, you still have to format CellRendererText objects the old way - they can't use CSS for formatting. Is that correct?
My current issue is I would like to load a font to use in my app, either from a web server or from a local file. This kind of thing works on a web page, but not in PyGTK3:
@font-face {
  font-family: CharisSILCompactWeb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local("Fonts/CharisSILCompact-Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
}

Actually on the web page I use url() instead of local(), since browsers don't like loading fonts from the local machine, for security reasons. But when I try to put this (either version) into the GTK3 CSS for my app, I get something like this:
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: :15:0unknown @ rule (1)
So I'm guessing maybe @font-face rules aren't allowed in GTK3 CSS? But I don't really see what is allowed or excluded. Is the docs.gtk.org page a complete list of everything allowed?
So is there some way that I can tell PyGTK3 to load and use a particular font?
